# How to write JavaScript code to duplicate HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, duplicates

Suppose I have an HTML element (like a `<div>`). Is there a way to duplicate it after a click using JavaScript?

If yes, is it possible to change the content of the duplicated HTML element to something else?

EDIT: Yes, I was asking how to do it as well. Thanks to the guys who answered my question!

Comment: Like a what? Can you clarify?

Comment: For your question, yes, yes, both possible.

Comment: This question is likely to be received negatively, and may lead to down votes and/or closure votes.  Instead of asking yes/no questions ("is it possible..."), you should ask concrete questions.  Also, instead of just asking *how* to do something, you should ask *why* something you tried to do isn't working.

Comment: @Gab: You should [edit] your question and include a minimal HTML excerpt, explain _exactly_ what to click, what should be duplicated and how it should be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on original element, set [`Elment.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of cloned node.

```html
<a href="#">a</a>
<script>
  var clone = document.querySelector("a").cloneNode();
  clone.innerHTML = "b";
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

See [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

```
$('a').clone().html("something else");
```

Comment: thats jquery. fyi.

Comment: @DanielA.White you're right, i realised after I posted that there was no jquery tag/specification